# How do deselect a particular SELECT option in a non multi-select selenium

Tags: selenium

```
Select sel41 = new Select(TestUtility.getElementByXpath("//[@id=\'supervisor_select_list_id\']"));
    //sel41.deselectByValue("167805");
sel41.selectByVisibleText("Employer Demo2 [HR Director]");
```

I want to deselect the default selected and select another value

Comment: You can just select a new value, no need to deselect the previous one.

Comment: Default selected value get selected.

Comment: If the dropdown has default value there is nothing you can do about it, you can't deselect it. But it doesn't stop you from selecting another value.

Comment: I have tried many time but it gives me first value only

Comment: @TahaYaseen Update the question with the relevant _HTML_